# How to choose area of integration for Stokes' theorem on a submanifold of a torus?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, stokes-theorem

This question is coming from physics, so I hope you will be patient as you read the following.

Setup: Assume all criteria for applying Stokes' theorem are met. Consider a 2D plane representation of a torus, where the left-right and top-bottom edges are identified with each other. On this plane, I choose a closed counterclockwise circular loop. Per my physics context, this loop defines the boundary of a submanifold on the torus. By convention, the area of integration for Stokes' theorem in this case would be the area **inside** the loop; and the area inside + the circular loop are respectively the region and boundary of the submanifold in consideration. The focus is on this submanifold, and not the common behavior of Stokes' on the entire boundary-less torus as discussed in other questions. Anyway, Stokes' theorem would then relate the line integral along this loop to the area integral of the region inside it.

Question: The above case of a circular loop is clear to me. However, one may also choose a circular loop on the torus by choosing either a vertical line or a horizontal line on the 2D plane. These lines are circular loops as well because the left-right and top-bottom edges are identified with each other. However, it is not clear to me how to apply the notion

Comment: one may note that indeed the vertical line or horizontal one are loops, but they are not the boundary of some domain, contrarily to the loop mentioned in the first part of your question. One can apply Stokes' Theorem only if the loop is the boundary of some domain.

Comment: @Giulio Thank you for the insight. Would you mind clarifying what exactly this entails in the context of choosing an area of integration? Many physicists take loops the second way (as straight lines), even in experiment. This question is coming from a point of applying the Gauss-Bonnet theorem with boundary to submanifolds specified by these loops. So, will the Euler characteristic in this case not be well-defined?

Comment: @Giulio I know that for a torus, one can specify boundaries only in two ways. But due to the physical motivation (physicists taking loops as lines), I want to understand what submanifold these other line loops specify. Especially because physicists somehow can tie these to observable, quantized quantities such as flux pumping.

Comment: I am sorry I think I am not able to answer more properly than that. What is not clear to me is how one would apply Stokes' Theorem to a loop which does not bound any domain, as far as I can tell this just goes beyond the range of applicability of Stokes' Theorem since just a horizontal line or just a vertical are not the boundary of any region in the torus (a certain composition is, however)

Comment: @Giulio I know that the following might not make sense mathematically, but my understanding is that the line defines a new manifold whose boundary is given by the line. So, the resulting object will not be the torus and will not necessarily share its topological properties.

Comment: @TribalChief As Giulio said, there is no submanifold of the torus whose boundary is the vertical or horizontal loop. One cannot expect computing any integral over these loops thanks to Stokes formula.

Comment: @Didier, thank you - I get it now. I am just confused now as to what exactly manifolds physicists consider when they take such vertical/horizontal lines. But that's something for physics stackexchange. If anyone would like to write up a brief answer based off these comments, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As people have commented, there is no Stokes's Theorem application here. What there *is* is a notion of periods (analogous to Gauss's Theorem with point charges in electrostatics for integrating over closed surfaces). If you have a closed $1$-form $\omega$ on the torus, its integrals over the "vertical" circle and the "horizontal" circle uniquely determine the cohomology class of $\omega$ (i.e., determine $\omega$ up to the addition of an exact $1$-form — corresponding to a conservative force field in physics terms).